# How can I mark a movie/series as watched on Netflix?

Tags: netflix

From what I understand, Netflix learns about your preferences and suggests movies/series based on that.

The problem is that this means that it doesn't know about a lot of my favourites because I have watched them before on other sites/cinemas/TV/etc. So how can I mark a movie or episode so that Netflix will learn that I like these?

Answer (score 6):

If you just rate the movie, it will be marked as watched.

Look [here](http://www.imore.com/how-rate-movie-or-tv-show-netflix-ios) on how to rate a movie in Netflix.

Comment: Oh thanks, that makes sense. Would I have to rate it highly for it to recommend similar shows, I tend to rate things very low, like a 2 for me would be just a 'meh, it was ok' show

Comment: Lol. Yeah, same here. To get 5 out 5 stars the movie or show just needs to be absolutely brilliant.

Comment: This is no longer a valid answer. On Android at least, there is only an thumbs up or down rating possibility. There's no 5 stars. So this question remains unanswered for me. I don't want to rate all the things I watched as up or down as sometimes a serie is just ok. How would you rate that?

Comment: I don't think Netflix has star ratings anymore. It is only up/down

Comment: This is not an answer as it doesn't answer how to mark a series as watched.

Comment: He’s right this answer is absolutely wrong.