# Netflix: mark as "read"

Tags: netflix

This was asked previously, but... [How can I mark a movie/series as watched on Netflix?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/97864/how-can-i-mark-a-movie-series-as-watched-on-netflix)

My problem is different. I have watched all the episodes of a series, and when a new season comes out, it will appear in `Continue Watching for JR` and suggest the first new episode. Once I finish the new season, it suggests I Continue Watching... an episode from an older season. This has happened for multiple shows. On Netflix's desktop site there is a way you can effectively mark something as "unread" by removing it from your watch history, but nothing to do the **opposite** unless you watch or rate each episode.

I can open up each episode one by one and skip to 1s from the end, but c'mon, there's got to be a better way. Right?

> ...right?